# Como retornar classes concretas, com propriedades de navegação preenchidas, por meio de consultas Linq?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, expressões-lambda

Seguindo essa pergunta: **[Consulta por Linq e Lambda obtendo range de opções por sub-query. Como obter um resultado mais próximo do simples?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37734/consulta-por-linq-e-lambda-obtendo-range-de-op%C3%A7%C3%B5es-por-sub-query-como-obter-um)** onde, porém, meu modelo cresceu para mais uma classe (resultando em mais uma tabela), a classe `Tela`, estou tentando selecionar alguns registros seguindo as seguintes regras dessa consulta `SQL`:

```sql
select MR.*, M.*, T.* from Auth_MenuRaiz MR
left join Auth_Menu M on M.MenuRaizId = MR.Id
left join Auth_Tela T on T.Id = M.TelaId
where T.Id in (
  select GAP.TelaId from Auth_GrupoAcessoPermissoes GAP
  where GAP.GrupoAcesso = 2
)
order by MR.Ordem, M.Orde
```

Estou testando o programa **[Linqer](http://www.sqltolinq.com/)** para me ajudar a entender a migração das consultas **SQL** em **Linq/Lambda** e, ao usá-lo para converter meu **SQL**, ele me retorna o seguinte comando **Linq**:

```cs
from MR in CRMContext.Auth_MenuRaiz
join M in CRMContext.Auth_Menu on MR.Id equals M.MenuRaizId into M_join
from M in M_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
join T in CRMContext.Auth_Tela on M.TelaId equals Id = T.Id into T_join
from T in T_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
where
    (from GAP in CRMContext.Auth_GrupoAcessoPermissoes
    where
      GAP.GrupoAcesso == 2
    select GAP.TelaId).Contains(T.Id)
orderby
  MR.Ordem,
  M.Ordem
select new {
    Id = MR.Id,
    Descricao = MR.Descricao,
    Ordem = MR.Ordem,
    Column1 = (int?)M.Id,
    MenuRaizId = (int?)M.MenuRaizId,
    Column2 = M.Descricao,
    TelaId = (int?)M.TelaId,
    Column3 = (int?)M.Ordem,
    Column4 = (int?)T.Id,
    Url = T.Url
}
```

O resultado do teste dessa Linq está correto, mas enfrento agora um problema.
A princípio, com o EntityFramework por meio de consultas Lambda, é possível obter a carga das propriedades das classes utilizando o comando Include:

```
_context.MenuRaiz
    .Include(x => x.Menus)
    .Include(x => x.Menus.Select(m => m.Tela))
```

Não consigo fazer isso com Linq, ou estou fazendo de forma errada.
E, claro, o resultado obtido pela consulta Linq não é exatamente uma instância de `MenuRaiz`, com sua propriedade de navegação `Menus` preenchida e, da mesma, a propriedade `Tela` preenchida. Na verdade a consulta **Linq** me retorna um objeto anônimo (modelo `dynamic`) com algumas proprieades.

Minha pergunta é, como conseguir o mesmo tipo de resultado? Ou seja, classes reais construidas como se estivesse fazendo a consulta por meio de **Lambda**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fazendo isto:

```
select MR.*, M.*, T.* from Auth_MenuRaiz MR
```

Ou isto:

```
select new {
    Id = MR.Id,
    Descricao = MR.Descricao,
    Ordem = MR.Ordem,
    Column1 = (int?)M.Id,
    MenuRaizId = (int?)M.MenuRaizId,
    Column2 = M.Descricao,
    TelaId = (int?)M.TelaId,
    Column3 = (int?)M.Ordem,
    Column4 = (int?)T.Id,
    Url = T.Url
}
```

Você está criando um objeto anônimo, portanto, `dynamic`.

Se é do seu desejo retornar um objeto tipado, o correto seria criar este objeto (a meu ver, um *ViewModel*) e então fazer nele a atribuição.

Sobre o `Include`, é um método implementado apenas no Entity Framework para a sintaxe chamada *Extension Methods*. O LINQ não é equivalente esta abordagem: ele pode até atuar como um envelope para as consultas, mas não possui todas as funcionalidades implementadas.

O `join` do LINQ não é equivalente ao `Include`. Embora o resultado possa ser bem parecido a abordagem é diferente.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, Então **para o EntityFramework**, **Linq** não efetua inclusões como o **Lambda** e o **Lambda** não faz `left join` como o **Linq** (pergunto, no caso, sobre carregar as propriedades de navegação)? Posso então concluir com isso que **para o EntityFramework**, pelo menos, não existe forma direta de filtrar os registros das propriedades de navegação (como com um `left join`) e obter classes concretas?

Comment: Sobre a primeira pergunta, o Linq não efetua inclusões, de fato, mas por *expression methods* (nome correto pro que você chama de lambda) é possível sim fazer `left join`. Sobre a segunda, sim, você pode filtrar usando cláusulas especiais para filtrar, como `Where()`, `Any()`, `All()`, e assim por diante.